# reason for pointer to a const pointer when using static_cast

Tags: c++, constants, static-cast

I have tried to solve an exercise from a book but I failed on the static_cast. I used the [qsort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/) Method from cstdlib. I have to cast the parameters of my function to a C-String (const char*). But I always get the error message: stattic_cast from type 'const void*' to type 'const char**' casts away qualifiers.

```
int scmp(const void *s1, const void *s2) {
    const char *c1 = (static_cast<const char**>(s1));
    const char *c2 = (static_cast<const char**>(s2));
    ....
}

const char *sfield[] = {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five"};
qsort(sfield, 10, 4, scmp);
```

The solution is as follows

```
const char *c1 = *(static_cast<const char* const*>(s1));
```

What is the reason for the last const and where does it come from? Why I have to cast to a pointer to a **constant** pointer to char const?

Answer (score 4):

It comes from the origin pointer. `static_cast` may not discard the const qualifier. So you can only cast `void const*` to a `T const*`.

Now, it just so happens that your `T` is a `char const*`. You were probably led astray by the leading `const` in your original code. It does not apply where one may think it applied.

Comment: What you say is correct, but isn't the problem of OP that the cast should be to `const char*` and not `const char**` or `const char* const *` in the first place?

Comment: @Haatschii - `qsort` provides pointers to elements of the array. The array contains `chat const*` *as elements*, so the pointer will have to be `char const* const*`. As for the OP's example, I think they just forgot to dereference the result of the cast when initializing their local pointers.

Comment: I've tried many things: `const char *c2 = (reinterpret_cast<const char*>(s2));` results in something like this `std::cout << "\n c2: " << c2 << '\n';  ->  ↔@@` with `const char* const *` it works fine.

Comment: @StoryTeller My bad, didn't realize that `qsort` calls the compare function with void pointers (which makes sense when realizing its a C-function). Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

The `qsort` comparator parameters are pointers to const versions of the elements being compared. In your example the elements being compared are `const char *`, so a pointer to const of that is `const char * const *`.   Hence the correct version of the code:

```
int scmp(const void *s1, const void *s2) 
{
    auto pc1 = static_cast<const char * const *>(s1);
    auto pc2 = static_cast<const char * const *>(s2);

    char const *c1 = *pc1;
    char const *c2 = *pc2;

    return strcmp(c1, c2);  // or whatever
}
```

You can do away with `pc1`, `pc2` and apply `*` operator to the result of the cast if you like .

Perhaps you mistakenly assumed the arguments were the elements being compared, when in fact they are pointers to the elements being compared .

If it is still not clear then maybe it would help to use a symbolic name for the element type:

```
using ELEMENT_T = const char *;

int scmp(void const *s1, void const *s2) 
{
    auto pc1 = static_cast<ELEMENT_T const *>(s1);
    auto pc2 = static_cast<ELEMENT_T const *>(s2);

    ELEMENT_T c1 = *pc1;
    ELEMENT_T c2 = *pc2;

    return strcmp(c1, c2);  // or whatever
}
```

The same pattern would work for elements that are not pointers (e.g. integer elements).